# ensuring a specific type outcome in SML

Tags: sml

Im trying to make a function that will return an element of type "point":

```
type point = {x : int, y : int};
fun pointadd (p1: point, p2: point) = (((#x p1) + (#x p2)), ((#y p1) + (#y p2)));
```

but [SMLNJ](http://www.smlnj.org/) doesn't seem to understand my intention that the result should be of type "point" as well:

```
use "test1.sml";
[opening test1.sml]
type point = {x:int, y:int}
val pointadd = fn : point * point -> int * int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`point` is a record type, but you are returning a tuple instead.

How about something like this:

```
fun pointadd (p1: point, p2: point) =
    { x = #x p1 + #x p2,
      y = #y p1 + #y p2 };
```

You can add a type guard on the return type to make the type nicer, but it's equivalent:

```
fun pointadd (p1: point, p2: point) : point =
    { x = #x p1 + #x p2,
      y = #y p1 + #y p2 };
```

Comment: @loldrup: If the problem is solved, you should **Accept** this answer, by clicking the green check mark underneath the vote counter.

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite a while since my SML days but afair the type system does not resolve defined types automatically when printing the type signature. You could try something like this:

```
fun pointadd (p1: point, p2: point) = (((#x p1) + (#x p2)), ((#y p1) + (#y p2))): point
```

Comment: that returns a syntax error:

- use "test1.sml";
[opening test1.sml]
type point = {x:int, y:int}
test1.sml:3.39-3.88 Error: expression doesn't match constraint [tycon mismatch]
  expression: int * int
  constraint: point
  in expression:
    ((fn <pat> => <exp>) p1 + (fn <pat> => <exp>) p2,
     (fn <pat> => <exp>) p1 + (fn <pat> => <exp>) p2): point

uncaught exception Error
  raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20